# Geräusch für "Pferd stoppen"

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es im Deutschen einen Laut, den man macht, wenn man ein Pferd stoppen möchte und an den Zügeln zieht?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laut Duden macht man das Geräusch

> [brr](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/brr).

Diese Interjektion ähnelt dem Geräusch, das man macht, um zu zeigen, dass einem kalt ist.
Dabei handelt es sich eher um ein Geräusch als ein Wort (auch wenn es im Duden steht).
Der entsprechend übliche Gegenlaut (um das Pferd zum Beschleunigen zu bringen) ist ein [Schnalzen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schnalzen) (Bsp. 4 im DWDS), das ich nicht ausschreiben kann.
Bei YouTube kann man sicher Beispiele finden.

Tatsächliche Wörter, die der Kommunikation mit dem Pferd dienen und den gleichen Zweck erfüllen:

> [hott](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hott) (Vorwärts! / Rechts!) und [hü](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hue) (Vorwärts! / Halt!).

Answer (score 8):

Willst Du wissen, wie es klingt, oder suchst Du einen Fachausdruck dafür?
Falls ersteres, wäre das wohl "Brrrrrrr" - da ich selbst nicht reite, kenne ich das allerdings nur aus Büchern und Filmen (vor allem Western).

Comment: Doch, doch, meine ländliche Verwandtschaft hat das auch gesagt. Als sie noch keinen Traktor hatten, sondern ein Pferd und einen Ochsen. (Das Pferd hieß übrigens Fritz, der Ochse Wulle.)

Answer (score 4):

Das gebräuchlichste Wort ist sicherlich das bereits in den anderen Antworten erwähnte

> Brr!

Im südbadischen, bzw bayrischem Raum gibt es allerdings noch folgende Begriffe

> [O! oh! oha!](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/oha), bzw [öha!](http://www.ostarrichi.org/forum.html?topicid=539)